# Can the roots of the derivative of the polynomial in complex variable be as close as we want them to be from the roots of the polynomial itself?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

The (probably) famous [Gauss-Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem) states that the roots of the derivative $P'(z)$ are contained in the convex hull of the roots of $P(z)$, where $P(z)$ is complex variable polynomial.

I am interested here in could it be the case that we always have some polynomial of any degree (except $1$) $P(z)$ such that some root of its derivative is "at a small as we want distance" from some root of $P(z)$.

To be more precise, here is the statement of the question:

> Is it true that for every $\varepsilon>0$ and for every $n\in \mathbb N \setminus \{1\}$ there exists polynomial $P(z)$ in complex variable of degree $n$ with $n$ different roots such that there is root $z_a$ of $P'(z)$ and root $z_b$ of $P(z)$ which are such that we have $|P'(z_a)-P(z_b)|<\varepsilon$

Comment: Yes, start with a polynomial with a double root and perturb the coefficients.

Comment: @MichaelBurr All roots are different in the question, if that changes anything?

Comment: If you insist that the coefficients of the polynomial are bounded integers, then the answer is no.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  After perturbation, the roots will all be different, but because the roots depend continuously on the coefficients, there will be a root of the derivative arbitrarily close to a root of the function.

Comment: @MichaelBurr If we choose some $\varepsilon_0>0$ is there an easy way to construct some concrete polynomial for every degree $n>1$ (it is a sequence of polynomials for every concrete $\varepsilon>0$ ) such that the question holds? I do not see immediately that this is the case.

Answer (score 7):

Let $P(z) = (z-\epsilon)(z-2\epsilon)\cdots (z-n\epsilon).$ Using the mean value theorem we can see that every root of $P'$ is less than $\epsilon$ away from some root of $P.$

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(z)=(z-\epsilon)(z+\epsilon)\prod_{i=1}^{n-2}(z-i)$.  This is a perturbation of the polynomial $z^2\prod_{i=1}^{n-2}(z-i)$, removing the double root.